# CSS Not working in IE8, IE9 but working in IE10 and above

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have this div for which id is generated on **runtime**, and css i have one template it will also be generated on runtime. The problem here is it is working fine in IE10 and above but in IE8 and IE9 for some div style is changing. Say i am **having 39 divs** but correct style is applying **only for 27divs.**

```
<loop>[for loop]
<div id="active<%count%>"> </div>
</loop>

<style>
#active<%count%>{
  height: <%(count < 5 ? count * 4 + 32 : "120")%>px;
  width: <%(count < 5 ? count * 8 + 32 : "80")%>px
}
</style>
```

Above code is used for creating divs and css. Height and Width is also generated on runtime this just a sample numbers. Can you guys help me to solve this. I am using this div to generate *GRID* using *ActiveWidgets 1.1*

Final code will be like

```
<style>
#active28{
  Height : 72px;
  Width : 112px;
}
</style>
```

It is same for both working and non-working in *View Source*.

Comment: Could you include the final generated code in your question please.

Comment: CSS looks OK to me, are you able to reproduce this issue in a Stack Snippet or JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use class for applying CSS?

```
<loop>[for loop]
<div class="active"> </div>
</loop>

<style>
.active {
 height: 752px;
 width: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: this is not a constant sized div i just written a simplified version of the code. It has some more conditions for applying height and width

Comment: well then, add some more code so we can help you, I am guessing it has to be a better solution than to generate ids and css selectors like this.

Comment: i have added code as you asked